# Find the limit $(\frac{n}{n+5})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find the limit -$$\left(\frac{n}{n+5}\right)^n$$

I set it up all the way to $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n+5}{n}\right)}{-\dfrac{1}{n^2}}$ but now I am stuck and do not know what to do.

Comment: Is it $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathrm L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+5}\right)^n \implies \ln {\mathrm L}=\lim_{n \to \infty} n \underbrace{\left(\frac{\ln \left( 1-\frac{5}{n+5} \right)}{\frac{-5}{n+5}} \right)}_{\text{This limit is 1}} \times \frac{-5}{n+5}$$$$ \implies \ln{\mathrm L}=\lim_{n \to \infty}n \cdot \left(\frac{-5}{n+5}\right)=-5$$

$$\implies \mathrm L=e^{-5}$$

Comment: A little confused on the middle step here. Why did -5/n+5 go in the denominator and where did the ln go after that step?

Comment: That limit is $1$. It's very popular limit that -$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1$$

Comment: Also, that $\frac{-5}{n+5}$ is in the denominator because I have multiplied and divided by that. See it in the product too.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to turn it over.

$\left(\frac{n+5}{n}\right)^n
=\left(1+\frac{5}{n}\right)^n
\to e^5
$
so
$\left(\frac{n}{n+5}\right)^n
\to e^{-5}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{n}{n+5} = 1 + \frac{-5}{n+5} $

Answer (score 0):

Just $$\left(1-\frac{5}{n+5}\right)^{-\frac{n+5}{5}\cdot\frac{-5n}{n+5}}\rightarrow e^{-5}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+5}\right)^n=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{5}{n}\right)^n}=$$
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\left(\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{5}}\right)^{\frac{n}{5}}}_{=e}\right)^5}=\frac{1}{e^5}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the fundamental limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e\tag{1} $$ Taking reciprocals we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n} {n+1}\right)^{n}=\frac{1}{e}\tag{2}$$ And note that the above limit holds if $n$ is replaced by $n+k$ where $k$ is some fixed integer so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n+k} {n+k+1}\right)^{n+k}=\frac{1}{e}$$ and hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n+k} {n+k+1}\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+k}{n+k+1}\right)^{n+k}\left(\frac{n+k}{n+k+1}\right)^{-k}=\frac{1}{e}\cdot 1^{-k}=\frac{1}{e}\tag{3}$$ We can now see easily that $$\left(\frac{n} {n+5}\right)^{n}= \left(\frac{n} {n+1}\right)^{n} \left(\frac{n+1} {n+2}\right)^{n} \left(\frac{n+2} {n+3}\right)^{n} \left(\frac{n+3} {n+4}\right)^{n} \left(\frac{n+4} {n+5}\right)^{n} $$ From $(3)$ we can see that each factor on the right of above equation tends to $1/e$ and hence the whole expression tends to $1/e^{5}$.

Using this approach starting from $(1)$ we can easily show via simple algebraic manipulation that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right) ^{n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}=e^{x}$$ for rational $x$.